# Running Multiple LDAP trees OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is it possible to have multiple seperate LDAP trees on a single LDAP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have to create multiple database entries in the base configuration and configure them with different `Base DN`'s.

This is done with the `database` statement in the `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`.

Example:

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "uid=root,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"
```

You will find more information in OpenLDAP's documentation.

(Note: Of course, this should also be possible to be configured via the `cn=config`  online configuration).